# how to sort list of dictionaries by value in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

**I have the original variable**:

```
files = {'1.txt' : [{'Line number': 1, 'file number': 1},
                   {'Line number': 2, 'file number': 1}],
         '2.txt' : [{'Line number': 1, 'file number': 2}]
        }
```

I need to sort the files by 'Line number' (although reverse, from least to the most, like this:

```
2.txt
total lines 1
Line number 1 file number 2
1.txt
total lines 2
Line number 1 file number 1
Line number 2 file number 1
```

I was writing code, but I have stuck with many lines and made it very complex. Any idea about simpler few lines of code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```py
sorted_files = {
    f: sorted(ll, key=lambda x: x['Line number'])
    for f, ll in sorted(files.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
}
```

Printing `sorted_files` you get:

```py
for f, ll in sorted_files.items():
    print(f'{f}\ntotal lines {len(ll)}')
    for l in ll:
        print(' '.join([f'{k} {v}' for k, v in l.items()]))
```

```bash
2.txt
total lines 1
Line number 1 file number 2
1.txt
total lines 3
Line number 1 file number 1
Line number 2 file number 1
Line number 3 file number 4
```

Note: starting from Python 3.6 onwards, the `dict` type keeps the order of the insertion. So, iterating through the items of `sorted_files`, you will always get the right sequence of items. If you are using an older version of Python, you should not use a `dict` if you want to keep the order of the items, but instead, you should use a `tuple` of tuples or a `list` of lists (or any combination of `list` and `tuple`). So, you should use the following code:

```py
sorted_files = [
    (f, sorted(ll, key=lambda x: x['Line number']))
    for f, ll in sorted(files.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
]
```